# multiplication table with flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to create a simple Flask application that takes in url parameters and returns the times table. The code I used is:

```
@app.route ( '/multiply/<x>' )
def get_table( x ):
    y= (x, x*1, x*2)
    return tuple(y)
```

I've tried creating a list of the products and passing x though them, this doesn't work unless I assign a value to x by hard coding it. Currently trying a simple function with a list and getting the error:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using flask template to call the function so where your x comes from?
Try this:

```
@app.route ( '/multiply/<x>' )
def get_table( x ):
    y= (x, x*1, x*2)
    return tuple(y)
```

and go to your_url/multiply/your_x_value

Comment: I've tried this and the error: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) keeps popping up